# How to make a inverted list of elements in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count, tf-idf

I have a master list of all terms and many child lists (All of them are stored in file and I am reading them from file), these list in files looks like how I have written them below. I want to find the inverted list i.e. no of occurrence of element in different document.

```
masterList={ 'token1' : 30, 'token2' : 28, 'token3' : 27, 'token4' : 26, 'token5' : 24, 'token6' : 20, 'token7' : 19, 'token8' : 18, 'token9' : 15, 'token10' : 12, 'token11' : 10, 'token12' : 6}  
idFCount={ 'token1' : 0, 'token2' : 0, 'token3' : 0, 'token4' : 0, 'token5' : 0, 'token6' : 0, 'token7' : 0, 'token8' : 0, 'token9' : 0, 'token10' : 0, 'token11' : 0, 'token12' : 0}  
childList1={ 'token1' : 6, 'token2' : 6, 'token3' : 3, 'token6' : 3, 'token7' : 2,  'token11' : 1, 'token12' : 1}  
childList2={ 'token1' : 10, 'token2' : 3, 'token3' : 1, 'token12' : 1}  
childList3={ 'token4' : 8, 'token6' : 7, 'token8' : 7, 'token9' : 3, 'token10' : 2,  'token11' : 2, 'token12' : 1}  
childList4={ 'token1' : 9, 'token5' : 6, 'token6' : 5, 'token8' : 3, 'token7' : 3,  'token9' : 1, 'token12' : 1}  

directoryList=['childList1' , 'childList2', 'childList3', 'childList4']  

for directoryName in directoryList :  

    for elements in directoryName.items() :  
        print (elements)
        idFCount[element[0]]=idFCount[element[0]]+1
```

From the above question I want an output like:

```
idFCount={ 'token1' : 3, 'token2' : 2, 'token3' : 2, 'token4' : 1, 'token5' : 1, 'token6' : 3, 'token7' : 2, 'token8' : 2, 'token9' : 2, 'token10' : 1, 'token11' : 2, 'token12' : 4}
```

But when I am doing it I am getting wrong value

Note:  In the above code the directoryList is not working but in orignal one I am loading pages

```
docTypetermfrequency = open(directoryName, 'rb')  
fileTermFreq = pickle.load(docTypetermfrequency)  
for elements in fileTermFreq.items() :  
    idFCount[elements[0]]=idFCount[elements[0]]+1
```

You may find all code and input outout file here.

Comment: My guess would be that your initialization of `idFCount` is either incorrectly done or in the wrong place. The "original" code snippet that you've posted doesn't show where and how you're initializing `idFCount`. Also, that code snippet seems to have some extra unwanted back-ticks (backward single quotes) -- probably you introduced them while posting your question here.

Comment: Actually, after fixing some typos, the code works fine and produces the desired result.

Comment: @tobias_k I have added the orignal code and input / output file at github, please have a look.
there you may see the wrong output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two errors:

```
directoryList={'childList1' , 'childList2', 'childList3', 'childList4'}  # First error

for directoryName in directoryList :  

    for elements in directoryName.items() :  
        print (elements)
        idFCount[element[0]]=idFCount[element[0]]+1 # Second error
```

your code should be:

```
directoryList=[childList1 , childList2, childList3, childList4] 

for directoryName in directoryList :
    for elements in directoryName.items() :
        print (elements)
        idFCount[elements[0]]=idFCount[elements[0]]+1
```

Comment: this code gives you the result you have been asking for:  idFCount={ 'token1' : 3, 'token2' : 2, 'token3' : 2, 'token4' : 1, 'token5' : 1, 'token6' : 3, 'token7' : 2, 'token8' : 2, 'token9' : 2, 'token10' : 1, 'token11' : 2, 'token12' : 4}, or you want something else, sorry maybe I skip something in your post? @Ali Abbas

Comment: I am really sorry for the above comment, Your answer is perfect, I was missing that only. Kindly up-mark the question as down mark is negating my rank here in stackOverflow.
Again thanks a lot.
@ncica

Comment: No worries, I am glad that I can help :) @Ali Abbas